# How to remove Volume slider from Control Center

Tags: iphone

When I swipe my home screen from bottom to top, I see below screen :

[image]

However I want to customise this screen like I want to remove the volume icon from this screen.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 1):

That screen is called the Control Center.

On iOS 14, go to "Settings -> Control Center".

From there, you can add, remove, and rearrange most of the controls that you see on that screen.

Controls such as Volume and Screen Brightness are there by default and can't be removed.  Perhaps if you jailbreak there's something to remove those controls but it's not possible with default iOS.